# Semantic UI, Dimmer Background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-color, semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui modal and I want to change background color of its dimmer but I cant.
I used

```
function modalist(){
    $(".ui.modal").modal("show");
    $(".ui.dimmer").css("background-color", "Yellow");
}
```

It works, but for less than two sec.
Please Help Me.
Kindest Regards;

Answer (score 3):

Try this css with "!important":

```
.ui.dimmer
{
    background: rgba(100, 100, 0, 0.85) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing css in a css file?

Comment: Yes, But I feel there is a JS code that change its color automatically after 2,3 seconds.